# Java Socket server accepts only one request and stops receiving data

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, server

I am making a Client-Server Java Swing application where I need to send requests through ObjectOutputStream. I make one request from LoginFrame to check if login/password is correct, server receives data, makes manipulations with it and successfully sends answer back. But when I try to make another call to server, it just doesnt receive it, server kind of stops listening.

Server:

```
public void runServer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server started and listening " + port);
        Model.getCountriesAndCities();
        System.out.println(Model.getCountries()[0]);
        System.out.println(Model.getCountriesMap());

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("serversocket accepted");
            System.out.println("before oos");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("before ois");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("server is listening");

            Map<String, Object> methodData = (Map<String, Object>) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Server: data received");

            String methodName = (String) methodData.get("method");
            Object arguments = methodData.get("arguments");

            Object result = invokeMethod(methodName, arguments);

            oos.writeObject(result);
            System.out.println("Server: data sent");
            oos.flush();
        }
    }
```

Client methods:

```
public static int checkUser(String login, String password, Client client) {
        String query = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '" + login + "' and password = '" + password + "') as isExist";
        String methodName = "CRUDUtils.checkUser";
        try {
            Map<String, Object> methodData = new HashMap<>();
            methodData.put("method", methodName);
            methodData.put("arguments", query);

            client1.oos.writeObject(methodData);
            System.out.println("Client: query sent");
            client1.oos.flush();

            int check = (Integer) client1.ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("chekUser: answer received");
            return check;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

```
public static String[] getCountries(Client client) {
        String query = " ";
        String methodName = "Model.getCountries";
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        ObjectInputStream ois;
        try {
            Map<String, Object> methodData = new HashMap<>();
            methodData.put("method", methodName);
            methodData.put("arguments", query);

            client1.oos.writeObject(methodData);
            System.out.println("Client: query sent");
            client1.oos.flush();

            System.out.println("before ois");
            String[] check = (String[]) client1.ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("getCountries: answer received");
            return check;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I also have Client class to start socket and swing Frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client klientura = new Client();
        try {
            klientura.socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
            klientura.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(klientura.socket.getOutputStream());
            klientura.ois = new ObjectInputStream(klientura.socket.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("client connected");
            Control.client1 = klientura;
            LoginFrame loginFrame = new LoginFrame(klientura);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to replace ObjectOutput and InputOutput, it didn't work.
I tried to flush every oos after sending data, it didn't work.
I tried to close every oos and ois after using them, it didn't work.
I tried everything, thats why this code right now is a mess.

Method checkUser works just fine, but when it comes to run getCountries, the client process just stops on line
`String[] check = (String[]) client1.ois.readObject();`
The last message in client console is "before ois", it means that `client1.oos.writeObject(methodData)` is completed, but server doesnt respond to that.
The last message in server console is "Server: data sent", it means that server sent data to checkUser method and stopped listening.

Comment: Try closing your output streams.

Comment: I'd also close the `clientSocket` in the server if you're not going to continue to re-use it

Comment: Your server presently loops accepting a connection, reading one item, sending one response, then looping to accept another connection. So try a read loop in the server. Presently you only have an accept loop.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Closing the output stream will close the socket.

Comment: @user207421 Won't closing the socket close both the streams?  Wouldn't that be, generally, a cleaner solution?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It will close both the streams but it won't flush any buffered output stream. Closing that output stream closes the lot, with flush.

Comment: @Max isn't the essence of using Sockets is to make a connection between two sockets and use it for a long time?

Comment: But you aren't using it for a long time. You're reading one request and sending one response. Next time around the loop you've lost the `Socket` reference, so you can never use it again, so you've leaked it. No virtue in that. Close it once you've sent the final response, or got an EOS from the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept--), accept() listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

Your current implementation looks like it is re-using the same connection for each request. Therefore, the server is blocking at the accept() method because the client is never making a new connection.

I would suggest leveraging threading on the server. On the main thread listen for new connections. Once a connection is made, the accept() method will return a Socket instance. At this point create a new thread and pass in the socket reference. Have all of the request/response processing logic in the new thread.

**This will allow you to read and write to sockets, while also listening for new connections to the server.**

```
public void runServer() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    System.out.println("Server started and listening " + port);

    while(true){
        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            Task task = new Task(socket);
            (new Thread(task)).start();
        } catch(IOException e){
            // Handle 
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;

    public Task(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Loop that reads from and writes to socket
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is at the server end, not the client end.

Comment: @user207421 I have revised my answer to hopefully be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I decided to make new socket connection on client side every time I need to send/receive data and it worked!